# Replace special character php

Tags: php, string

I have a problem right now. When someone is ordering something which contains the character "æ", it make it into "à¦", which destroys the mysql query, and ends the sentence there. For an example i got this:

```
#55*2*195*1 - 1,%%%%38. Burger dobbelt %%%%Kommentar%%%%Burgeren skal và¦re med friske agurker i stedet for syltede%%%%og uden ost. Pà¥ forhà¥nd tak %%%%%%%%100. Lasagne %%%%Dressing%%%%Ingen dressing,*;;124.20;;Niklas Smietana;;;;7;;*#
```

But when it insert it into the database, it ends up being like this:

```
#55*2*195*1 - 1,%%%%38. Burger dobbelt %%%%Kommentar%%%%Burgeren skal v
```

It just ends there.
So what i want to do is that i want to replace every special characters like "æ", "ø", "å", "ü", "ö" and so on, in the "string", so it becomes "ae", "oe", "aa", "u", "o".
I have tried with str_replace but it wont do it.

My code:

```
$product_name = $row['product_names'];
$product_name = str_replace("Ã¸", "oe", $product_name);
$product_name = str_replace("Ã‰", "É", $product_name);
$product_name = str_replace("Ã", "à", $product_name);
$product_name = str_replace("¿", 'oe', $product_name);
$product_name = str_replace("¾", 'ae', $product_name);
$product_name = str_replace("æ", 'ae', $product_name);
$product_name = str_replace("Œ", 'aa', $product_name);
$product_name = str_replace("å", 'ae', $product_name);
$product_name = str_replace("š", 'oe', $product_name);
$product_name = str_replace("Ÿ", 'u', $product_name);
```

Do anybody in here have a solution on that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats your charset of the file and collation in db?

Comment: See [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to prevent mysql injections and to escape special characters.

Comment: Could you please give an example, because when i try to:

    $product_name = utf8_encode($product_name);

it just edits the line into:

    #55*2*195*1 - 1,%%%%38. Burger dobbelt %%%%Kommentar%%%%Burgeren skal vÃ Â¦re med friske agurker i stedet for syltede%%%%og uden ost. PÃ Â¥ forhÃ Â¥nd tak %%%%%%%%100. Lasagne %%%%Dressing%%%%Ingen dressing,*;;124.20;;Niklas Smietana;;;;7;;*#

Comment: @IsmailIsmaiil I edited my post and deleted the utf8_encode answer I had written.